# GoogleApiClient crashes when I add a second API

Tags: java, android, google-api

I've implemented google sign in, but when I try to add leader boards it crashes immediately, I have run out of google results to read.

My App successfully logs me in when I build an API as such:

```
private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {

return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .build();
}
```

But THIS version crashes the app:

```
  private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
  return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
  .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
  .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
  .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
  .build();
  }
```

Here is the output in LogCat on crash:

```
    12-23 15:09:43.613: D/AbsListView(11516): Get MotionRecognitionManager
    12-23 15:09:43.643: W/PopupManager(11516): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
    12-23 15:09:43.673: D/Activity(11516): #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
    12-23 15:09:43.764: I/Adreno-EGL(11516): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
    12-23 15:09:43.764: I/Adreno-EGL(11516): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
    12-23 15:09:43.764: I/Adreno-EGL(11516): Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
    12-23 15:09:43.764: I/Adreno-EGL(11516): Local Branch: 
    12-23 15:09:43.764: I/Adreno-EGL(11516): Remote Branch: 
    12-23 15:09:43.764: I/Adreno-EGL(11516): Local Patches: 
    12-23 15:09:43.764: I/Adreno-EGL(11516): Reconstruct Branch: 
    12-23 15:09:43.794: D/OpenGLRenderer(11516): Enabling debug mode 0
    12-23 15:09:43.854: D/AndroidRuntime(11516): Shutting down VM
    12-23 15:09:43.854: W/dalvikvm(11516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417d3da0)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516): Process: com.flung.patryk, PID: 11516
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.b(Unknown Source)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.g(Unknown Source)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$b.hy(Unknown Source)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    12-23 15:09:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(11516):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Finally, here are my enabled API's

[image]

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Check your meta data again~ again again

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
```